# Mercurial Integration(bitbucket) with TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, bitbucket

I am using Bitbucket and also Mercurial. I want to integrate TeamCity with this setup.

I created a public key and private key.

I can use this command on my build server:

```
hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/companyname/projectname
```

and it works fine.

But when I do the configuration on Teamcity it just creates an empty folder and it does not work and does not raise an error.

mercurial.ini file

```
[ui]
ssh = "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\TortoisePlink.exe" -ssh -2 -i "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\PrivateKey.ppk"
```